# ELI5: Help me understand remediation / debugging when functional tests fail on mobile apps (iOS or Android)

Tags: debugging, appium, android-espresso, functional-testing, xcuitest

Situation: QA runs functional tests on real devices, using any framework like Appium or XCUITest, or Espresso. Let's say you have true positive failures. These QA folks only know how to zip up the logs and send them over to you in engineering...

My question is: What is the ELI5 process for remediation or debugging? You look at which logs first typically? The Device logs? If you have a stack trace of a fatal exception what do you do? You load up your IDE like XCode and go to that portion of the code? Are there tools for log analysis? (something you just import logs into, and get some sort of point in the right direction?) What's good about the way QA passes bug information back to you, and what could be incrementally better?

Comment: This question is waaaay  too broad. You should narrow down the scope  of what  you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It honestly depends on the product and other internal policies. But from a general point of view, when QA finds a bug and logs it somewhere, be it Jira, internal tools etc. they should be providing some reproduction steps for the said bug. This way, you as a developer can reproduce the issue using the steps provided by QA. Of course, in cases of app crashes, it's highly recommended to attach at least a crashlog :)